# Настройки программы

Tags: .net, c#

Есть необходимость хранить настройки программы (пути, переменные). Больше всего подходит вариант "настройки хранятся в папке с программой". Что лучше для этого использовать? Я думаю, может xml?

Comment: Используй XML, не ошибёшься.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложно что-то посоветовать, не зная конкретики.

Если это настройки, которые не будут меняться на конкретной машине, либо будут меняться только админом (грубо говоря, человеком с подходящей квалификацией) - удобно их хранить в файле app.config

Если это настройки, которые будут меняться из самой программы, то вариантов куча, можно, например, хранить в реестре системы. Можно действительно в файле в папке с программой. Тогда, в общем, пофигу, в каком виде хранить: хоть в бинарнике, хоть в ini-файле - вопрос простоты парсинга и сохранения настроек и читабельности файла (если есть такая необходимость). Xml-формат хорош тем, что достаточно хорошо читаем и при этом можно очень легко сделать xml-сериализацию (десериализацию) объекта с настройками.

Answer (score 6):

Реестр лучше не использовать, т.к. в случае, если пользователь будет с ограниченным доступом вы просто не сможете записать значения в реестр. В идеале лучше написать свой класс для сериализации/чтения настроек приложения, но также можно использовать Application.Properties.Settings (см. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Стандартные подходы такие:

- [реестр](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) Windows,
- объект [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397750.aspx).

В большинстве случаев возможностей Properties достаточно.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше всего хранить настройки в виде xml-файлов в профиле пользователя.

Settings / app.config - не самый лучший способ, так как у пользователя может не быть прав на то, чтобы писать в папку с программой. В них лучше хранить какие-нибудь настройки библиотек, которые входят в состав продукта и пользователем не редактируются.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще хранить настройки в папке с программой не всегда разумно, так как здесь, также как и с реестром, возникают проблемы с правами того, или иного пользователя. В своих проектах я храню настроки так:

- Глобальные настройки (для всех пользователей) хранятся в реестре (ветка HKLM), их может менять только администратор.
- Настройки для конкретного пользователя я храню тоже в реестре, но в ветке HKCU, так как к ней есть доступ.
- Также, в некоторых проектах храню настройки для конкретного пользователя в INI-файле, в его документах, либо в общем файле в публичных документах.
- Сейчас также рассматриваю вариант хранения настроек на сервере.

Вообще при выборе места хранения всегда руководствуюсь несколькими пунктами:

- Возможность ПОЛНОГО удаления настроек при удалении программы. (Многие программные продукты оставляют за собой массу мусора в виде "настроек")
- Изоляция пользователей друг от друга
- Удобство и скорость доступа.