# Где и как правильно хранить настройки программы?

Tags: c#, config, settings

Программа на С# (но в принципе это не столь важно), до этого использовал стандартный app.config, быстро удобно, но его возможностей стало не хватать. Во первых параметров стало много: сохранение состояний всех окон, некоторых контролов, настройки самой программы, настройки подключения к серверу, которые надо шифровать ну и т.д. В общем решил написать свой велосипед, теперь думаю где это все хранить, и соответственно как реализовать.

На данный момент склоняюсь к созданию своего класса настроек и его бинарной сериализацией, но вот вопрос, где его хранить? Не хотелось бы его держать в папке с программой, и для каждого пользователя иметь отдельные настройки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тогда храните в профиле текущего пользователя. А сериализацию лучше делать через xml, чтобы при необходимости можно было поправить конфиг руками.

Comment: Так и сделаю. Вот еще инфа по теме:
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/development/70922/

Answer (score 4):

На форуме был уже похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13820/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#13895), посмотрите, возможно найдете полезным