# Save settings in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Здравствуйте !
написал программу по C#, но не знаю как сохранить настройки в visual studio 2012 ? 
как это делается, можете помочь ?

Comment: Простите, настройки чего?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос по сохранению настроек программы поднимался неоднократно, посмотрите, в этих ответах есть полезные ссылки и описание возможных вариантов:

1. [Где и как правильно хранить настройки программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23755/c-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)
2. [Настройки программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13820/c-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о настройках программы, то тут вариантов много:

- свой текстовый/бинарный файл
- сериализация объекта, который хранит настройки в файл
- ini файл (классика:) )
- реестр.
- какое нибудь с# специфическое решение.